# Uploading Large file over httpPost throws unknown error in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, file-upload, http-post

I have a simple ractive angular form for uploading files, and there's ASP.core for backend.
sending the file to the api over HTTP post stops midway after like 10 seconds and returns an UNKNOWN ERROR with code 0 only if the file is larger than around 10MB or so. small sized files are uploaded just fine.

The ASP.NET API as of now just returns a message after recieving the form and no proccessing. So the file won't even reach the server. Plus, sending the same large files with Postman works just fine. and there's no limit on file size on the Backend so the problem has to be the client-side.

I even rewrote the code using [this](https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/) tutorial. result is the same even though it works with Postman but my angular app fails.

```
progress: number;
message: string;
@Output() public onUploadFinished = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

uploadFile = (files: any) => {
 if (files.length === 0) {
   return;
 }
 let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

 this.http.post('https://localhost:44468/api/upload', formData, { reportProgress: true, 
  observe: 'events' })
    .subscribe({
     next: (event: any) => {
       if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
         this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
         this.message = 'Upload success.';
         this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
       }
     },
     error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => console.log(err)
   });
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file" (change)="uploadFile(file.files)" style="display:none;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="file.click()">Upload File</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <span class="upload" *ngIf="progress > 0">
    {{progress}}%
  </span>
  <span class="upload" *ngIf="message">
    {{message}}
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

the Error:

[image: unknown error]

Hence I have no Idea why the error occurs and no way to rectify it.
Keep in mind that there's no problem uploading smaller files. It can't be CORS issue since it works with postman and `AllowAnyOrigin() ...` is set.
I'll gladly appreciate any help.

Comment: Any errors from the back end? Could it be a limit on file upload size?

Comment: @E.Maggini Could it still be a backend problem even though Postman can send the same files to the server with no problem? doesn't make sense. I've disabled requestSizeLimit and etc on API and web.config as well. But not sure, don't really know how to check IIS back-end log directly.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Increase the maximum file size allowed by the client-side configuration of your Angular application. Angular may have a default limit on the size of files that can be uploaded, which could be causing the error you are experiencing. You can increase this limit by adding the following code to your app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'MAX_FILE_SIZE', useValue: 10000000 } // 10 MB
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2-Check for network issues or timeouts. The fact that smaller files are uploaded successfully suggests that the issue may be related to network congestion or a timeout. You can try increasing the timeout value for HTTP requests by adding the following code to your uploadFile function:

```
const httpOptions = {

  headers: new HttpHeaders(),
  reportProgress: true,
  observe: 'events',
  timeout: 120000 // 2 minutes
};

this.http.post('https://localhost:44468/api/upload', formData, httpOptions)
  .subscribe({
    next: (event: any) => {
      // ...
    },
    error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.name === 'TimeoutError') {
        // Handle timeout error
      } else {
        // Handle other errors
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately added both and it's still the same. Strange thing is there's one or two `HttpEventType.UploadProgress` which increases the progress but then it just suddenly stops. and after a few seconds it shows the unknown error.

Comment: are you setting the header to     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
 ?

Comment: yes. it's `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: okay my last suggestion will be to add maxBodyLength: Infinity  to the httpOptions  , hope it works